# Simple example to describe Bilinear mapping

Tags: group-theory, functional-encryption

Notation : $\mathbb{G}$ is an additive group and $\mathbb{G}_T$ is multiplicative group of prime order $q$.

Bilinear mapping $e: \mathbb{G} \times \mathbb{G}  \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_T$ has to satisfy two properties.

1) $e(aP,bQ) = e(P,Q)^{ab}$        for all $P,Q \in \mathbb{G} , a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_q$

2) $e(P,P) \ne 1_{\mathbb{G}_T}$ for all $P \in G$

In addition to the above two, it has to be computable.

Is there any simple example for such bilinear pairing?

I searched over internet as I can but I didn't find.

I want example like this $e(x,y) = xy \mod n$ (It's not a valid example).

Note: The sets under consideration $\mathbb{G},\mathbb{G}_T$ must have at least four elements.

Duplicate question for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380004/simple-example-for-bilinear-mapping

Comment: Mathematically, a bilinear map need only satisfy the first condition. Sadly, cryptographers are keen to appropriate mathematical terms and give them a different meaning...

Comment: @fkraiem It indeed makes sense to make this second property explicit in context of cryptographic applications. Bilinear maps that do not have this property would be useless for how they are used in cryptography.

Comment: Asking for examples is considered off topic. I've slightly altered the title, hope you agree.

Answer (score 4):

A toy example would be this simple map with $\mathbb{G} = \mathbb{Z}/5$ to $\mathbb{G}_T = \mathbb{Z}^*/11$, as follows:

$$e(x,y) = 3^{xy} \bmod 11$$

It's easy to verify that both equations hold (except that $e(0,0) = 1$; that's actually a necessary consequence of the first equation, and so I'll consider that an acceptable exception).

Of course, even if you scale this up to non-toy sizes, this particular style of bilinear mapping isn't cryptographically interesting; however it does answer your question.

Comment: Here order of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is 5 and of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^*$ is 10, how they both can be of same prime order as i specified in my OP.

Comment: @hanugm: actually, in my case, $\mathbb{G}_T$ really is the group of quadratic residues modulo 11, and the size of that group is 5.

Comment: Is there any reason for selecting 3 in this case? Can is use any number co-prime to 5 and 11 instead of 3?

Comment: @hanugm: I selected 3 because the order of 3 (mod 11) is 5; that is, $3^5 \bmod 11 = 1$ and $3^x \bmod 11 \ne 1$ for $0 < x < 5$.  Any such value with this property will work, and in fact, 5 will (in fact) work.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is none (as far as is currently known). From Ben Lynn's doctoral [thesis](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/thesis.html) on the subject:

> There is only one known mathematical setting where desirable pairings
>   exist: hyperelliptic curves.